# Can any trusted security sources recommend Eraser - eraser.heidi.ie (a Windows Application)?

Tags: security, secure-erase, review

Anyone familiar with the quality/security of the secure erasure application **ERASER**?

Or come across any articles from experts about it?

http://eraser.heidi.ie/

Comment: http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did found this case study that is mentioning Heidi:

> A free tool (donations accepted) that is very robust and allows you to
>   wipe free space (more accurately called “unallocated clusters”) as
>   well as slack space (also called “cluster tips”) is Eraser. In
>   addition, it includes the ability to configure your system to wipe the
>   page file at shutdown. It includes a scheduler to allow you to
>   schedule how frequently you would like the program to run. **It is a
>   well-designed and easy to use application.**

Source: [Sans.org (PDF from 2006) - Page 11](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/incident/secure-file-deletion-fact-fiction_631)

The case study references this comparsion:

http://www.sdean12.org/Comparison_Shredders.htm (also from 2006)

They list Eraser (when it was still developed by Sami Tolvanen) as **Recommended**, and this for any version that was available at that time.

Answer (score 1):

With over 900,000 downloads, CNET has a pretty good rating on it, located here: http://download.cnet.com/Eraser/3000-2092_4-10231814.html

I've personally used it in conjunction with products like Recuva, and without a hitch it does do it's job at least on the low level stuff.

Comment: [I wouldn't trust cnet ](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/cnet-downloadcom-not-so-spyware-free/2148) though i often  recommend eraser for easy security wiping